# python lxml find <fb:comments /> tag

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse an html that has a facebook comments tag that looks like that:

```
<fb:comments id="fb_comments"  href="http://example.com" num_posts="5" width="600"></fb:comments>
```

I am trying to select it to get the href value but when i do a `cssselect('fb:comments')` i get the following error:

```
The pseudo-class Symbol(u'comments', 3) is unknown
```

Is there a way to do it?

**Edit:**
The code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
html = '...'
parser = fromstring(html)
parser.cssselect('fb:comments')  #raises the exception
```

Comment: Please provide your python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`cssselect()`](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html) method parses the document using given [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) expression. In your case the colon character (`:`) is a XML namespace prefix separator (i.e. `<namespace:tagname/>`) which is confused with CSS pseudo-class syntax (i.e. `tagname:pseudo-class`).

According to [lxml manual](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html#namespaces) you should use `namespace-prefix|element` syntax in `cssselect()`in order to to find a tag (`comments`) with a namespace prefix (`fb`). So:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
html = '...'
parser = fromstring(html)
parser.cssselect('fb|comments')
```

Comment: great! thanks,
but that is returning `Undefined namespace prefix` any idea why?

Comment: Maybe try with just `comments` (w/o namespace) ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860013/xhtml-namespace-issues-with-cssselect-in-lxml on how to use namespaces with cssselect.